# Format columns depending on whether text in A contains word in the header of the columns

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am using Google Forms to collect data in a Google Spreadsheet. In one of the columns (A), several strings of text are received. I would like to format columns B to E depending on whether or not the text in A contains the word in the header of columns B to E:

```
Row/Column     A                       B      C        D           E
1                                     VB     DCE    Reporting   Redovisning
2            VB, Reporting
3            Reporting, Redovisning
4            DCE
5            VB, Redovisning
```

Ideally, I would then want B2 and D2 to become colored because the text in the respective headings can be found in A2 (and so on for the remaining columns and rows). I have managed to do so using "custom formula is":

```
=if(countif(A2;"*VB*");TRUE;FALSE)
```

but I would like to replace `"*VB*"` with B1 to make the formula easier to use.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please select B2:E5, Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is:

```
=match("*"&B$1&"*";$A2;0)
```

with formatting of your choice.